# Chrome Browser Auto Save causing to hide the popup calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

In our application that uses bootstrap calendar on focus of a text box, the chrome auto save entries are masking the calendar. This happens only for the first time and if the user clicks outside of the textbox and clicks back in, we no longer have the issue until next page refresh.

Any ideas / thoughts on how to fix this? (Please refer to the image attached)[image: Image showing the issue]

Comment: What happens if you set autocomplete="off" on your options or dropdown?

Comment: Issue does not occur if the "auto fill" forms feature is set to off. However this is up to the user :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set Chrome and Firefox to ignore form completion by setting the "autocomplete" attribute to "off":

Assuming the above is a combo box:

`<input type="text" id="theinput" name="theinput" autocomplete="off" />
   <select> . . .</select>`

Asks Chrome and Firefox to not form fill this field. You can fairly rely on adherence since this is required behavior for a card processing.